# How can you acknowledge a PubSub message in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to know what is the correct way to acknowledge a PubSub message (from a push subscriber), which is a Firebase Cloud Function. Is this done by returning a promise?

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

export const listener = functions.pubsub.topic('new_members').onPublish(async (message:any) => {

let data = {
  name: 'Los Angeles',
  state: 'CA',
  country: 'USA'
};

// Will a PubSub message be acknowledged just by retuning a promise?
return await db.collection('cities').doc('LA').set(data);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you ask, does it work? Here are corresponding docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function completes successfully by returning a resolved promise, the messages will be ACK'd.  If the function throws an exception or returns a rejected promise, then pubsub will retry the message.

Comment: @doug-stevenson, is it still valid for firebase functions? I do not see attempts to re-deliver messages, when `functions.pubsub.topic..onPublish` return rejected promise

Comment: Can you share a link to some documentation or quote an external source? Because it does not seem to be true.

Comment: To be more specific, the retry part seems to be incorrect

Comment: @seza443 The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) states "Note: Cloud Functions acks the message internally upon successful function invocation. For information on how to handle failures using retries, see Retrying Background Functions."

Answer (score -1):

Note: Cloud Functions acks the Pub/Sub message internally upon successful function invocation. When retries are enabled, Cloud Functions can re-invoke a function that has failed during execution using the same Pub/Sub message.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions_calling_pubsub-java